# How to dynamically change view in Swift (e.g. for a settings page)?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I found a good settings page tutorial at https://www.simpleswiftguide.com/how-to-use-userdefaults-in-swiftui/ and implemented it into my app. However, the settings page is completely static and can't be changed based on the user's choices. Often a program needs to have constraints where the allowed choices for field B might change based on the user's choice of field A. How do I add an on-click listener to the settings which can call the UIViewController to somehow change the structure of the view after it has already loaded? I am using `UIHostingController` to wrap the SwiftUI `View` which is declared as a struct instead of a class. If I try to access the view via `self.view` I don't see any relevant functions that could give me access into the inner workings or fields of the view.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like there's an easy way to do this in Swift like there is in Android. I'll resort to using a sequence of `UIAlertController` each with multiple choices. Unlike the View struct with "var body" protocol, the alerts can be built programmatically depending on what the user has already set.

Answer (score 0):

Some `if else` in the `View`

```
if $userSettings.username.wrappedValue == "username"{
    SomeView()
}else{
    SomeOtherView()
}
```

Comment: I tried something similar to this in the HostViewController but it only takes 1 view during init. I can't figure out how to pass other views after it's already been initialized. Also it would be a last-resort solution because the # of views I'd have to create would be exponential to the # of branches in the choices

Comment: You can have a ManView() and then within the MainView you can make the decision above but I guess with some sample code we could figure out a solution.